# AVAudioPlayer will not play audio for one mp3 but will for others?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

All of my other audio files play perfectly through the audio player. Most of the files are less than 5 seconds long, and the longest file that still plays is 23 seconds long. For some reason my 1:15 long file "sortSong" is completely silent when it is called.

Here is the code for my audio player:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class AudioPlayer {

    static let sharedInstance = AudioPlayer()

    enum Sound: String {
        case sortSongPlay = "sortSong"
        case centerButtonRelease = "centerButtonRelease"
        case buttonTap = "tapSound"
        static var all: [Sound] {
            return [.centerButtonRelease, .buttonTap, sortSongPlay]
        }

        var url: URL {
            return URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.rawValue, ofType: "mp3")!)
        }
    }

    private var soundMap = [String: SystemSoundID]()

    init() {
        for sound in Sound.all {
            let soundUrl = sound.url
            var soundId: SystemSoundID = 0
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundUrl as CFURL, &soundId);
            soundMap[sound.rawValue] = soundId
        }
    }

    func play(sound: Sound) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundMap[sound.rawValue]!)

    }
}
```

The sound is played when this function is called in my view controller.

```
func successfulSort() {
    AudioPlayer.sharedInstance.play(sound: .sortSongPlay)
    rotateSortImageOne()
    rotateSortImageTwo()
}
```

This is the action that calls the successfulSort func

```
  if inputText == "hello" && seedArray == [1, 4, 1] {
    successfulSort()
}
```

If I simply change the case sortSongPlay to = "shortSortSong" (the 23 second version) it plays just fine.

All of my sound files have their target memberships checked for this project file, and all of the files have the correct path. The audio will play in the interface builder if I press the play button. There are no compiler errors or warnings, the app never crashes, the audio for sortSong simply isn't playing when it is called in the app.

This is a link containing examples I have tried on my project. The first two sounds play silently in the app while the shorter sounds all play perfectly. https://soundcloud.com/spiffystache

What is causing this to be silent?

Comment: I have encountered issues in the past where an encoding issue with the file prevented playback. I re-encoded the file and it worked for me afterwards. May be worth a try?

Comment: I'll give this a try when I get home in a few hours.

Comment: I just tried adding 2 more audio files of similar length and replacing sortSong with them and neither would play :(. I also tried a much shorter audio file (4 seconds) using the same encoding and that one did play.

Comment: Can you share the sample audio file which is creating an issue? I can test it out with that file.

Comment: The first 2 sounds on this page do no work. The shorter sounds all work. https://soundcloud.com/spiffystache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a correct title on your question.

Your code does not use `AVAudioPlayer`, but uses [System Sound Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/system_sound_services).

The documentation clearly states its limitation:

> You can use System Sound Services to play short (30 seconds or
>   shorter) sounds.

I have never checked if its limitation is exactly 30 seconds, but it matches the description in your question.

Consider using `AVAudioPlayer` (as in the title) to play longer sound.